# sometime SetCookie() not working

Tags: php, setcookie

Hi I created two file to switch my forum (Language Chinese and English)

**enForum.php**

```
<?php

     function foo() { 
        global $_COOKIES; 
        setcookie('ForumLangCookie', 'en', time()+3600, '/', '.mysite.com'); 
        echo 'running<br>'; 
        $_COOKIES['ForumLangCookie'] = 'en'; 
        bar(); 
    } // foo() 


    function bar() { 
      global $_COOKIES; 
      if (empty($_COOKIES['ForumLangCookie'])) { 
              die('cookie_name is empty'); 
            } 
            echo 'Language  =' . $_COOKIES['ForumLangCookie'];
            echo "<br>";
    } // bar() 

    foo();


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>forum EN Version</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>

please be patient ...
<script LANGUAGE='javascript'>

   location.href='http://www.mysite.com/forum/index.php';

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**cnForum.php**

```
<?php

     function foo() { 
        global $_COOKIES; 
        setcookie('ForumLangCookie', 'cn', time()+3600, '/', '.mysite.com'); 
        echo 'running<br>'; 
        $_COOKIES['ForumLangCookie'] = 'cn'; 
        bar(); 
    } // foo() 


    function bar() { 
      global $_COOKIES; 
      if (empty($_COOKIES['ForumLangCookie'])) { 
              die('cookie_name is empty'); 
            } 
            echo 'Language  =' . $_COOKIES['ForumLangCookie'];
            echo "<br>";
    } // bar() 

    foo();


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>forum CN Version</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

please be patient ...
<script LANGUAGE='javascript'>

   location.href='http://www.mysite.com/forum/index.php';

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are some files including `include template('logon');`,`include template('regist');` etc, I write some code to get the Cookie value and control the flow to load different template files.

```
$lang = $_COOKIE["ForumLangCookie"];
// for Debug
// echo '$lang is '.$lang;
// echo '<br/>';

if ($lang == "cn"){
    include template('logon');
}
else if ($lang == "en"){
    include en_template('logon');
}
```

But sometime the SetCookie() not working. Do I need add `Sleep(someSeconds);` for my code?

Comment: There is no need for using `global $_COOKIE` - this array is one of [several predefined superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and it's accessible from everywhere.

Comment: You might include only one of the code examples in the question, as they seem to be almost the same.

Comment: @mkj, I suppose user click the url link to triger different Language configuration. That's why I created two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies can be accessed with `$_COOKIE`,not `$_COOKIES`.

EDIT:Sorry for misunderstanding. I suggest you to change the variable `$_COOKIES` as another common one so people can understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP array name is $_COOKIE, not $_COOKIES